# How to set up Selenium and ChromeDriver to run in headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xunit

I am trying to run a browser test using xUnit, Selenium, and Chrome Canary (headless mode) but I keep getting this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL 
http://localhost:58692/session timed out after 60 seconds.
```

Here's my code:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
    {
        BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe",
        DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222"
    };

chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox", "headless", "disable-gpu");
_driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions) {Url = Url};
```

I'm quite new to C# so I'm not sure if I'm doing something blatantly wrong, or if I'm just missing a setting. Googling the above error told me that I need to set the debugger address and use the `no-sandbox` flag, but neither seem to be helping.

Using these versions:

```
selenium 3.4
chromedriver 2.29
xunit 2.2
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I had to use Chrome 60 beta to get it to run headless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking out the debugger address made it work.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
{
    BinaryLocation = @"C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that others will get here while googling...

What worked for me was to download the latest chrome-driver from this link:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
            case "chrome9515headless":
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1200,900");
                chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-browser-side-navigation");

                webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9515"),
                    chromeOptions.ToCapabilities());
                break;
            case "chrome9515canary":
                ChromeOptions chromeOptionsCanary = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptionsCanary.BinaryLocation= @"C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe";
                //chromeOptionsCanary.AddArgument("--headless");
                //chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
                chromeOptionsCanary.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
                chromeOptionsCanary.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
                chromeOptionsCanary.AddArgument("--window-size=1200,900");
                chromeOptionsCanary.AddArgument("--disable-browser-side-navigation");

                webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9515"),
                    chromeOptionsCanary.ToCapabilities());
                break;
```